# What database should I choose not to worry about size limit?

Tags: delphi

I want to make rather simple database, which should store videofiles, and soundfiles. I wanted to use MS Access database (mdb), but this is limited to **2 GB**. 
I do not want to use server - client solution, cause it should be single application using only local database stored on local harddrive. That's the idea.

May you give me an advice?

thanx

Comment: Which Delphi are you using?
 
What is the size of the largest media file?

Do you want to store the media files as BLOBs?

or can the files be stored in local directories with only the metadata in a database.

Comment: Delphi 7. Filesize is not specified. I assume that the largest videofiles should take an hour of playing (length of an lecture), but I do not know compression rate yet.

Comment: The Database you are looking for is called the FileSystem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd go with embedded [Firebird](http://firebirdsql.org/). You can have a maintenance-free desktop application and if you want you can scale it later on to a full C/S system. Also you have enough libraries (free or not - Zeos, UIB, IBObjects, FIBPlus) to use it from Delphi. Not mentioning that the latest Delphi has a DBX driver OOTB.

Also, having large amounts of data in the database blobs (if you design it right) doesn't affect the search speed.

HTH

Comment: I am not sure about Firebird... Once I thought over, which DB system should I choose and I end up with MySQL (because of price issues). I think Firebird is not free...

Comment: @lyborko: Firebird is free. See details here: http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=doc&id=idpl

Comment: @lyborko: and check MySQL Licence http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html

Comment: Firebird is very efficient/fast with storing blobs, it's free and does not have nasty licensing issues like MySQL. I use Firebird in one project for storing 60,000 XML and PDF documents in a database with 10kb..4MB sizes and all is performing well. It is now inproduction use for 5 years. Note that anyone with a database browser for Firebird (like IBExpert) can read the database and extract your precious blobs.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to store binary data like video/audio data, you should consider using the filesystem and putting metadata like width, height, length, author, ... in a database of your choice. I like MySQL.

Comment: Though for a local DB I'd probably use SQLite - there's a delphi version here http://sqlite4delphi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes this would heal my pain, but in that case I can not protect data. Can I deploy somehow MySQL engine together with this application (in one install.exe file) to run localy?

Comment: @lyborko - If you're worried about someone tampering with your data then look at storing them encrypyted and signed on the hard drive. Sticking them in a DB won't protect them anymore than storing them on the filesystem it just makes it a bit harder for people to mess with them

Comment: If your application is not GPL: MySQL is not free.

Comment: Afaik, using MySQL does not force you to license your software as GPL.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) is one of the best choice for [Delphi](http://wings-of-wind.com/2009/08/27/rad-studio-2010-community-pulse-the-day-after-part-1/) and one embedded version exist

And an article about Firebird and [blob storage](http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=1906)

Comment: That link only mentions write speed to the db - it doesn't mention the affect on search speed. Though Firebird does look cool though :)

Answer (score 1):

How about [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? That would be suited for your needs I'm sure, plus, it's public domain. There are bindings for different languages also. See [here](http://sqlite4delphi.sourceforge.net/) for the Delphi interface for Sqlite.

**Edit:** after zebrabox's comment - You can create a simple table to identify different resources and paths...something like this

```
CREATE TABLE "BlobId" (
    "BLOB_TYPE" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);
CREATE TABLE "BlobInfo" (
    "BlobInfo_Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "BlobInfo_Date" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "BlobInfoPath" TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

`BlobId` table would have the values 1 for Image, 2 for Audio, 3 for Video, and it would be logically linked  to `BlobInfo` table

```
BlobInfo
1, 2010-02-13 04:05:40  C:\Blobs\SomeImage1.jpg
1, 2010-02-13 04:05:40  C:\Blobs\SomeImage2.jpg
2, 2010-02-13 04:05:40  C:\Blobs\SomeSound.wav
3, 2010-02-13 04:05:40  C:\Blobs\SomeVide.mp3
```

By using Sqliteman which is the [Sqlite](http://sqliteman.com/) Manager GUI front-end for administering the Sqlite databases, will make the job easier. The onus is on you to make sure that the path is flexible enough to be moved in conjunction with the database.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I agree but I wouldn't put large data blobs in the db - I'd just store the metadata like Willi Schonborn suggested and have the media data on the file system

Comment: @Zebrabox: sure...can store the path to the actual blobs somewhere that is flexible enough for future proofing... :D

Comment: Can large data blobs seriously affect search speed of an application? I have not experiences with such big databases,.. Probably I'll try SQLite, thanx for suggestion...

Comment: @lyborko : They might do - depends on the DB. Having large blobs means that the db engine might not be able to fit any search results i.e temporary tables into memory so will use the disc instead which may cause slowdown. All depends on how big your media blobs are i.e 1Mb or 1Gb?

Comment: @tommieb75: thanx a lot. I will play with it later... :-)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested before I also recommend [FIREBIRD](http://firebirdsql.org). Delphi has Native Support for this, it requires minimal overhead in code, easy to install, zero maintenance, transportable if needed, super feature-set and best of all: it's totally free for even Commercial products.

Comparing MySQL and Firebird might be considered by some comparing a toy toolset (MySQL) to a real Pro's tools (Firebird). - *I hope this does not start a war...*

Answer (score 0):

I use [Advantage Database Server](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver)

and it has a local server option and very easy to use.
I have about 12000 records in my main table with some 70000 linked list table each with a picture and an audio file (full mp3 song) and about 800 video clips in the database.

all is working very good.

you should give a test.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is not embedded, but you can run it on your local machine (in a separate process). It can store BLOBs in the "bytea" data type. Open source and free.

PS I think the maximum size of a bytea field may be 4GB, because there's a four byte length field, but I can't see that explicitly stated in the postgres documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **DB2**. DB2 since version 9 supports very large tables. The maximum is monstrously large. **512000 petabytes**, half a zettabyte.

Answer (score 0):

We have used postgreSQL using Devart pg components with great success in medium sized database apps. We did some limited benchmarking with this combination and found it 2-3 x the speed of using ADO etc.